# How to automatically reload frame in EXTJS?

Tags: javascript, html, caching, iframe, extjs

I have an `iframe` component in EXTJS where I load external html file:

```
        {
                xtype: "component",
                border: false,
                layout: 'fit',
                flex: 1,
                autoEl: {
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '100%',
                    tag: "iframe",
                    src: 'resources/startpage/index.html'
                }
        }
```

I would like the iframe to automatically loads new content when I change the external html file, but it loads previous file that is in cache. Is there a way to do it?

By analogy with image files, I tried to put

```
src: 'resources/startpage/index.html' + '?_dc=' + (new Date())*1
```

but that doesn't work,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to bind it to the viewmodel

view.js

```
{
  xtype: 'container',
  bind: {
    html: '<iframe src="resources/startpage/index.html?_dc={myDc}" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none;"/>'
  }
}
```

viewmodel.js

```
 formulas: {
  myDc: {
    get(){
      return (new Date())*1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Robert R. That works. However, if the page I loaded contains link(s) to other page(s), for example ```<a class="myclass" href="about.html">About</a>```, and if I change the ```about.html```, the same problem pertains (with the page about.html). So, what would be the strategy to solve that? In addition, how can I include ```?_dc=``` in html?